# How to move camera when marker goes outside of the screen?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on map base application to animate marker. There are one marker which is updated against 30 sec interval from server. Marker always move to center of the Map ,so i close moveCamera marker but when marker move outside the map then marker is not come in map view. so i want to camera move when marker goes from map view

Comment: If you have the Marker in hand just gets its latlng and move the camera to it... its that simple map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

Comment: thanks for reply @OfekRon ,if i move the camera then marker always comes to the center of Map view. if user zoom the map,i want move marker when marker goes outside the map view.

Comment: you want to move the camera or the marker?

Comment: marker is moving perfectly . but when marker move and it goes out from visible map view then need to move camera.

Comment: Did you try map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); ? where latlng is the latlng of the marker?

Comment: yes,i did but when marker move all time center of map view

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before setting new position of the marker, check it's new position and current bounds of map view.

```
LatLng newPosition = new LatLng(...);

boolean contains = mMap.getProjection()
    .getVisibleRegion()
    .latLngBounds
    .contains(newPosition);

if(!contains){
    // MOVE CAMERA
}
// UPDATE MARKER POSITION
```

- During the marker's each new position inside map view, marker moves(not
  center of map)
- Just If next position goes out of view, camera and marker will be centered.

**Edit**

I created a sample route to simulate each point on map periodically. [Route gist](https://gist.github.com/blackkara/92fa21cef7abe868a815c09d4784905e)

```
public class SampleRoute {
    public static List<LatLng> GetPoints() {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new LatLng(38.4670419, 27.1647131),
            new LatLng(38.4667244, 27.1648277),
            new LatLng(38.4666633, 27.1649079),
            new LatLng(38.4665983, 27.1648022),
            new LatLng(38.4665958, 27.1647843),
            new LatLng(38.4665958, 27.1647843),
            new LatLng(38.4665809, 27.1646429),
            new LatLng(38.4665704, 27.1645506),
            new LatLng(38.4665529, 27.1644067),
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then i create a method in sample activity that calculates current region's bounds and marker's X, Y points on this region. [Activity gist](https://gist.github.com/blackkara/c53e615b748d78f68430295a33d25988)

```
private void moveCamera(LatLng destination){
    Projection projection =  mMap.getProjection();

    LatLngBounds bounds = projection.getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
    int boundsTopY = projection.toScreenLocation(bounds.northeast).y;
    int boundsBottomY = projection.toScreenLocation(bounds.southwest).y;
    int boundsTopX = projection.toScreenLocation(bounds.northeast).x;
    int boundsBottomX = projection.toScreenLocation(bounds.southwest).x;

    int offsetY = (boundsBottomY - boundsTopY) / 10;
    int offsetX = (boundsTopX - boundsBottomX ) / 10;

    Point destinationPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(destination);
    int destinationX = destinationPoint.x;
    int destinationY = destinationPoint.y;

    int scrollX = 0;
    int scrollY = 0;

    if(destinationY <= (boundsTopY + offsetY)){
        scrollY = -(Math.abs((boundsTopY + offsetY) - destinationY));
    }
    else if(destinationY >= (boundsBottomY - offsetY)){
        scrollY = (Math.abs(destinationY - (boundsBottomY - offsetY)));
    }
    if(destinationX >= (boundsTopX - offsetX)){
        scrollX = (Math.abs(destinationX - (boundsTopX - offsetX)));
    }
    else if(destinationX <= (boundsBottomX + offsetX)){
        scrollX = -(Math.abs((boundsBottomX + offsetX) - destinationX));
    }
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(scrollX, scrollY));
    mMarker.setPosition(destination);
}
```

And then started to simulate points

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        moveCamera(mPoints.get(mCurrentPos));
        if(++mCurrentPos < mPoints.size()){
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1500);
        }
    }
}, 1500);
```

I tried and it's working well on me

So, if i understand you correctly and it works for you too then i could explain.

Comment: ,thanks for reply.is it possible to just marker comes to view,don't not move to center?

Comment: If new position is out of map view,  camera must focus new position too otherwise how you see the marker ? This is exactly why I wrote above two things.

Comment: your answer working fine for me but i want just marker just come into view not move to center.os it possible to do?

Comment: marker and camera both.when marker goes outside the map view then move to camera but that time camera move to center of the map but i want that just marker comes into the map view not in center.is it possible?

Comment: Oh i think i got you, just wait

Comment: mean i want just like ..marker moving then map also moving together.thanks for your support.

Comment: i will try with your updated code and i will back to you with result.

Answer (score 1):

When marker location is updated you can animate the camera to the marker position. Following sample code may help you

```
  LatLng definedLoc = new LatLng(latitudeValue, longitudeValue);
  CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(definedLoc).zoom(13.0F).build();
  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can animate the camera to the Marker position if the map bounds does not contain the marker using a `GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener`:

```
private Marker marker;

// ...

@Override
public void onCameraChange(final CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    ensureMarkerOnBounds();
}

private void ensureMarkerOnBounds() {
    if (marker != null) {
        if (!mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds.contains(marker.getPosition())) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()));
        }
    }
}

// This is the function that you use to move your marker
private void moveMarker (Marker marker) {
    // ... Your code to move your marker
    ensureMarkerOnBounds();
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply @antonio ,can we move camera when marker is move out from mapview?

Comment: That's exactly what the example does

Comment: i will try and get to you.

Comment: Hi @antonio ,marker is moving but camera is not moving so marker is not in map view

Comment: Have you set the `OnCameraChangeListener` to your map doing `mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);`?

Comment: its working thanks for you support.but its taking some time there are any smooth transaction possible?mean when marker move outside then map also move?

Comment: i want to just marker comes in map view not in center just like cab application.it can be possible?